# How to add bars or strengthen a sliding door?

Tags: doors, security

I am trying to secure a home, by adding bars to the windows, and metal door to the front, as well as added locks to the garage door.

The back door has a glass sliding door. I can strengthen this with some extra lock on the interior, in the floor, or piece of wood, or suggestions [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/63935/how-do-i-secure-an-old-aluminum-glass-sliding-door) but that still presents thieves with a large area of glass to break through.

Is there any product that either, serves the same function and is an easy replacement for double sliding doors, that is strong, or that can be added to the outside or inside, making it very difficult to break in?

Comment: How much do you want to spend? Roll down steel shutters would tick all the boxes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If youre worried about someone breaking a glass door, stop.  First of all, there are much simpler ways to de-track a slider. Second, you can put all the bars you want on the door, but the thief can still break the glass and reach inside to release the lock & catch.

Similarly, garage doors are by design (for lightweighting) easy to crumple or kick in.

The simple fact is that a determined and experienced burglar knows more ways to get in, without doing significant damage or making noise, than you can imagine.  Unless your neighborhood has a history of breakins, it's not statistically worth while to take any extreme measures.  If anything, install an alarm system with automatic calls to first responders.